# ears on both sides or ear on both sides

Tags: american-english

I don't know which one is correct. Plural or singular.

- The ears on both sides of my face.
- The ear on both sides of my face.
- The safety fences at the machine side and the operator side.
- The safety fence at the machine side and the operator side.
- (2 fences in total)

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ears and there are two fences. So the nouns in question would be plural.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: But you could say _the ear on each side of my face_ - with "each", you would use the singular.

Comment: @ColinFine - personally, I'd say I have ears on both sides of my _head_, the face being the front part.